# jupyter notebookの.ipynbがchrome上でloadできなくて困っています...。

Tags: python, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebook上で.ipynbを開こう(view)としたところ、Something went wrong with displaying webpage ということでページが開かれないエラーが発生しました。
terminal上ではkernelもスタートしていますし、別の.ipynbはviewで開けています。
結局、応急処置として、visual studio codeにて回しています。
対策として何ができるでしょうか？

Comment: Chrome上の当該タブを閉じ, Jupyter Notebookも終了。その後に Jupyter Notebook再度立ち上げるとどうなりますか？

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
伺った通りの操作を経ても、状況は変わりませんでした...。

Comment: nbcleanを用いて、output出力をclearしたら開くことができました。
出力が大きすぎて開けなかったようです。ありがとうございました。